# How does Bayesianism deal with made up / post hoc explanations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

Consider the example of an object spontaneously going up in flames.

Now one hypothesis may be that it was (A) some chemical reaction, but another could be (B) an invisible man with a lighter.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Does it even make sense to consider B? (is there a methodology that would disqualify it as a valid explanation?)
2. How would you put a prior on B?

Even worse consider (C) an invisible being with unlimited powers that can do anything.

3. I've heard that "a theory that fits everything cannot explain anything". How is this expressed in Bayesian terms?

Lastly, it is my understanding that $E$ is (positive) evidence for $H$ if $P(E|H) > P(E|\neg H)$.
But by adjusting $H$ one can make $P(E|H) \approx 1$. But:

4. How is the connection between $E$ and $H$ made in the first place? (Does one need to demonstrate a causal relationship to even be able to consider $H$ as a possible explanation?)